# How to retrieve, with devops api on TFS 2015 the list of all the "project collections"

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve the list of all project collection on TFS 2015 server, with c# via devops API.  I don't have direct access to the TFS configuration database.

More of the solutions that I have found use old or deprecated methods like `tfsConfigurationServerFactory` class.

Comment: See codeproject which has full working code : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117462/TFS-API-TFS-Work-Item-All-Changes-History

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Project Collections API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/tfs/project-collections?view=tfs-2015)?

**Sample Request:**

```
GET https://mytfsserver/DefaultCollection/_apis/projectCollections/d81542e4-cdfa-4333-b082-1ae2d6c3ad16?api-version=1.0-preview.2
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
    "id": "d81542e4-cdfa-4333-b082-1ae2d6c3ad16",
    "name": "DefaultCollection",
    "url": "https://mytfsserver/DefaultCollection/_apis/projectCollections/d81542e4-cdfa-4333-b082-1ae2d6c3ad16",
    "state": "Started",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://mytfsserver/DefaultCollection/_apis/projectCollections/d81542e4-cdfa-4333-b082-1ae2d6c3ad16"
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "https://mytfsserver/DefaultCollection"
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/tfs/project-collections?view=tfs-2015#sample-code) to some sample C# code.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client.ProjectsAndTeams
{
    [ClientSample(CoreConstants.AreaName, CoreConstants.ProjectCollectionsResource)]
    public class ProjectCollectionsSample : ClientSample
    {

        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public IEnumerable<TeamProjectCollectionReference> ListProjectCollections()
        {         
            VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
            ProjectCollectionHttpClient projectCollectionClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectCollectionHttpClient>();

            IEnumerable<TeamProjectCollectionReference> projectCollections = projectCollectionClient.GetProjectCollections().Result;

            foreach(var collection in projectCollections)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(collection.Name);
            }

            return projectCollections;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes i have previously tried this type of solution, but in this case i obtain a "System.AggregateException"

Comment: You can't request a list of all collections when a collection is inside the request. For Azure DevOps you can request for `http://{server url}/_apis/projectCollections?` to get a list of collections. Unfortunately it's not coverd by a [vso.scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops). That mean, the request is illigal in `VSS_Auth_Service` context.